# How to write some encoding function in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, encoding

I need to write a string encoding function that returns the output as follows:

```
encode_string("Jack000Jons000446") ➞ { "given_name": "Jack",
"family_name": "Jons",
"id": "446" 
} 
encode_string("Ann0funs003567") ➞ { "given_name": "Ann",
"family_name": "funs",
"id": "3567" 
}
```

Furthermore:

- The string will always come in the same positional order
- The field "id" will never contain 0's

How can I write this type of function in Python Pandas/Numpy ?

Comment: Please can you show a specific piece of code that's not working. What have you tried? Seeing what you've tried could help us to give you a better answer for your problem.

Comment: Also, why are the pandas and numpy tags included? Or even better, is it OK if the solution does not use any of those libraries?

Comment: @aaossa the question is clear and pandas, numpy tags seems relevant. Could you please let me know why additional tags are irrelevant or the question is not clear?

Comment: Please don't clear questions after they've been answered -- it is not helpful for future readers, and it isn't respectful to people volunteering their time to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.split()`, splitting the string on one or more zeroes. `numpy` and `pandas` aren't really necessary for solving the problem.

```py
import re

def encode_string(s):
    given_name, family_name, id = re.split(r"0+", s)
    return {
        'given_name': given_name,
        'family_name': family_name,
        'id': id
    }

# Prints {'given_name': 'Jack', 'family_name': 'Jons', 'id': '446'}
print(encode_string("Jack000Jons000446"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to rename the function because it's really decoding rather than encoding. Therefore:

```
import re
def decode_string(s):
    return dict(zip(['given_name','family_name','id'], re.split('0+',s)))
print(decode_string('Jack000Jons000446'))
```

**Output:**

```
{'given_name': 'Jack', 'family_name': 'Jons', 'id': '446'}
```